# How do you install meteor on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, meteor

How can I begin with Meteor? Are there any simple tutorials such as a beginner's guide?

Comment: Have you gone on the Meteor webpage yet? http://docs.meteor.com/

Comment: There's a free ebook "Your First Meteor Application", which is located at  http://meteortips.com/book/introduction/  .

Answer (score 5):

Best place to begin with Meteor is the [Meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com) itself.

In addition to that, these are some of the nice articles to a gain grip on fundamentals of Meteor.

[andrewscala.com](http://andrewscala.com/meteor/) , [net.tutsplus.com](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/whats-this-meteor-thing/) and [andrewmunsell.com](http://www.andrewmunsell.com/blog/introduction-to-realtime-web-meteor-and-nodejs/#.UPZ91R3qlyN)

For installing Meteor on ubuntu, see this [Meteor Github](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/README.md#slow-start-for-developers) page.